# Show/Hide Text based on onchange of select

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS, there is a requirement to show a dropdown with a selected value: 
- When user selects a different value we should show a warning message and shouldn't proceed with update (save button disable). 
- When user reverts to the original value, the message should hide and able to update (save button enable)

```
<select ng-model="vm.sldetails.AgencyGroupID" onchange="" 
        ng-options="a.AgencyGroupID as a.AgencyGroupName for a in vm.agencygroups">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>  
<label ng-show="">Warning message</label>
```

Instead of calling an event in controller, can we achieve directly in Onchange event?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.sldetails.AgencyGroupID"                          
        ng-options="a.AgencyGroupID as a.AgencyGroupName for a in  vm.agencygroups">
           <option value="">--Select--</option>
     </select>             
</div>
```

HTML:

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-label text-align-left" id="lblWarningMessage" ng-if="vm.sldetails.AgencyGroupID==='your value'">Warning message</label>
```

In label tag,your value should be replaced by ur compare value

Comment: this value is not hardcoded. The original value (vm.sldetails.AgencyGroupID) comes from the database

Comment: then how will you comapre that value?? If it is coming from db,fetch from db assign to model and compare it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something like this:

```
<select ng-model="vm.sldetails.AgencyGroupID" ng-change="vm.selectChanged()" 
        ng-options="a.AgencyGroupID as a.AgencyGroupName for a in vm.agencygroups">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>  
<label ng-show="vm.showWarning">Warning message</label>
```

And in js:

```
vm.selectChanged = function(){
    if(vm.sldetails.AgencyGroupID !== 'the initial value'){
        vm.showWarning = true;
    }else{
        vm.showWarning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming you mapped 'this' to 'vm'